# Is there a way to directly migrate SAP BO reports into microstrategy?

Tags: business-objects, microstrategy

I have my existing BI reporting from the SAP BO software and now I want to migrate everything to MicroStrategy. So is there any way to migrate those reports to MicroStrategy directly or just if I can migrate the dimensions and measures created in SAP BO to Attributes and metrics in MicroStrategy. Please suggest a way to do that effectively.

I did research on this topic on other platforms like on MicroStrategy community and Google also, but all those did not answer my question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly there was once an internal tool in MicroStrategy to do that, I never used it and from what I remember it was quire rough and still required a lot of manual work.

You can try to read [this presentation from MicroStrategy](https://www.microstrategy.com/Strategy/media/downloads/event-support-documents/world-2016/presentation-slides/world2016_t6_s6.pdf) to have an idea about the process and the possible approaches.

Personally I did once a conversion from BO to MicroStrategy, it was possible to reuse most of, if not all, the tables created for Business Object, but in MicroStrategy I created everything from scratch, the design of the dashboards was different to make them more interactive/easy to use.

Of course this approach can appear not feasible with big projects (this is why colleagues were using the above mentioned tool), but I think rebuilding from scratch, with a small scope (small team) and build on it will give the best result in the long run. The main issue here is that this could take time and some times organizations don't want to wait, but this is their problem :)

Comment: @ Dipesh Hi, i have a similar situation where we have to migrate reports from SAP BO software to PowerBI. I am new to SAP and reports migration, any possible leads if it is achievable via rest api calls or any other method. It would be great if dont have to move data model. Here is my posted question......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776787/how-can-you-migrate-sap-bo-reports-to-powerbi