# How can you migrate SAP BO reports to PowerBI?

Tags: rest, crystal-reports, powerbi, migration, business-objects

can anyone please briefly guide me on Migration of SAP BO reports, Webi, Crystal Reports to Microsoft PowerBI. It would be better is underlying data model (Universe) is not migrated only reports, but it is not a necessary case if required data model can also be moved that would require more work.

Comment: Its all manual work and from scratch as per my knowledge.

Comment: @mkRabbani can you do that by calling api or using powershell of powerbi?